# Выполнение действия при изменении переменной класса

Tags: php, классы, переменные, объекты

### Описание

Имеется класс **Xtext**, в нем имеются переменные, одна из них **$name**, так-же в классе **Xtext** имеется функция **msg()**, которая выводит переменную **$name**.

---

### Выглядит это так

```
class Xtext
{
    var $name = 'Имя1';

    public function msg()
    {
        echo($this->name);
    }
}
```

> Как выполнить какой-либо код, при изменении значения переменной **$name**?

### Пример

Создадим в переменной **$test** объект используя класс **Xtext**.

```
$test = new Xtext;
```

Теперь изменим переменную **$name**, в объекте **$test**.

```
$test->name = 'имя2';
```

Мы изменили переменную, в объекте **$test**, именно в этот момент должен выполнится php скрипт. Например `echo("Переменная изменилась на $test->name");`

> Но как его выполнить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Я так понимаю переменная `$name`, да еще и с устаревшим атрибутом `var` не просто так определена в классе? Намеренно усложнить задачу? Она здорово мешает задействовать магические методы `__get()` и `__set()`, которые традиционно используются для решения подобных задач. Поэтому, сначала придется эту переменную уничтожить в конструкторе, а потом действовать при помощи упомянутых выше методов

```
<?php
class Xtext
{
  var $name = 'Имя1';
  private $data = array();

  public function __construct() {
    unset($this->name);
    $data['name'] = 'Имя1';
  }

  public function msg()
  {
      echo($this->name);
  }

  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    if($name == 'name') {
      echo "Переменная изменилась на $value";
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Can't set $name attribute");
    }
  }

  public function __get($name)
  {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$name];
    }

    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    trigger_error(
        'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
        ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
        ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
        E_USER_NOTICE);
    return null;
  }
}
$test = new Xtext;
$test->name = 'имя2';
echo '<br />';
echo $test->name;
```

Comment: Зачем `var $name = 'Имя1';` а потом на две строки ниже `unset($this->name);` Можно не обьявлять. Ну и `debug_backtrace` -  перебор.

Comment: Потому что это часть условия задачи. В разных языках эта задача решается по разному, когда у вас определен атрибут определен уже в классе именно в PHP задача значительно усложняется, так как вы не можете воспользоваться методами __get()  и __set(). Своим ответом я лишь хотел напомнить, что метод класса можно убрать в том числе средствами PHP, а не только руками. Здесь пример упрощен, но вам класс может достаться готовым, вы от него можете наследоваться и от него могут быть уже унаследованы другие классы - вы можете не иметь возможности убрать var $name = 'Имя1'.

Answer (score 2):

### Явным образом

Объявите поле как `private` и добавьте отдельный метод, который будет присваивать новое значение этому полю - сеттер.

```
class Xtext
{
    private $name = 'Имя1';

    public function setName($newName)
    {
        $this->name = $newName;
    }

    public function msg()
    {
        echo($this->name);
    }
}
```

Соответственно в коде вместо `$test->name = 'имя2';` использовать `$test->setName('имя2');`. Как что-то делать ещё, помимо изменения свойства - вроде уже очевидно. Частая и обоснованная практика - вообще не предоставлять публичный свойств, а только набор методов.

### Некоторое количество магии

PHP предоставляет несколько методов с особым поведением, так называемые [магические методы](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). В частности, возможно определить свою особую логику для обращения к несуществующим свойствам объекта.

```
class Xtext
{
    private $realName = 'Имя1';

    public function __set($field, $value)
    {
        if ($field == 'name') {
            $this->realName = $value;
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException('undefined field ' . $field);
        }
    }

    public function __get($field)
    {
        if ($field == 'name') {
            return $this->realName;
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException('undefined field ' . $field);
        }
    }

    /*
     * этот метод необходимо определить для корректной работы isset, empty, coalesce operator
     * его можно реализовать проще, сделал более явный вид для очевидности
     */
    public function __isset($field)
    {
        if ($field == 'name') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function msg()
    {
        echo($this->realName);
    }
}
```

Свойство realName при этом никак трогать не нужно. В общем-то, суть та же, скрыть реальное свойство. Магические методы позволяют не менять внешнее API класса, в коде может использоваться по-прежнему `$test->name = 'имя2';`

Comment: В дополнение к ответу – стоит начать с основ [ООП](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объектно-ориентированное_программирование) (инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм) + [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(объектно-ориентированное_программирование))